# Why it is open 2 windows when I pass arguments to a WPF application?

Tags: wpf

I want to pass 1 argument to a WPF application, so I have this code:

In my app.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        VariablesGlobales.RutaFicheroInformacionActualizacion = e.Args.FirstOrDefault();

        // Application is running
        // Process command line args
        bool startMinimized = false;
        for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (e.Args[i] == "/StartMinimized")
            {
                startMinimized = true;
            }
        }

        // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        if (startMinimized)
        {
            mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

But when I debug, two windows are opened.

I don't have more code, the main window is still empty, and it has not code in code behind.

How could avoid to open 2 windows or 2 instances of the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF project contains App.xaml file with StartupUri of a window, which is shown when an application starts.

```
<Application x:Class="ProjectNamespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNamespace"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and you create and show additional MainWindow instance (`mainWindow.Show();`)

since you need some configuring, remove StartupUri